# JavaScript appendChild for element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am attempting to use JavaScript to dynamically append child elements (li elements) into an existing list.

**Target DOM**:

```
<body>
  <div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
    <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
      <li class="dd-item" id="2879">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section123</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2880">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 4</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2881">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 5</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button value onclick='addSection()'>Add Section</button>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function addSection() {
  var data = { SectionId: 123, SectionText: 'Section Name'};
  var agendaDiv = $("[name='agenda-nestable']");
  var agendaSections = $(agendaDiv).find("ol#agenda-root");
  agendaSections.appendChild('<li class="dd-item" data-id="' + data.SectionId + '" id="' + data.SectionId + '">' +
      '<div class="dd-handle">' + data.SectionText + "</div></li>");
}
```

**Plunk**: https://plnkr.co/edit/jLi9epblNAtMbzezcRSY?p=preview

Could someone please take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong?  It seems like it should be straightforward, and I believe I am traversing the DOM correctly. :-/

Thanks,

Philip

Comment: sectionListItem is not defined

Comment: $(agendaDiv) makes no sense when agendaDiv is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `appendChild()` to `append()`:

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/27tdn4yc/)

```js
function addSection() {
  var data = { SectionId: 123, SectionText: 'Section Name'};
  var agendaDiv = $("[name='agenda-nestable']");
  var agendaSections = $(agendaDiv).find("ol#agenda-root");
  agendaSections.append('<li class="dd-item" data-id="' + data.SectionId + '" id="' + data.SectionId + '">' +
      '<div class="dd-handle">' + data.SectionText + "</div></li>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="dd" name="agenda-nestable" id="nestable">
    <ol id="agenda-root" class="dd-list">
      <li class="dd-item" id="2879">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section123</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2880">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 4</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" id="2881">
        <div class="dd-handle">Section 5</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button value onclick='addSection()'>Add Section</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

`appendChild` isn’t a jQuery function; it’s part of the DOM API, and you can only use it on DOM nodes. jQuery objects aren’t DOM nodes. There’s no reason to be manipulating HTML in the first place, though, when you can create an actual `<li>` element:

```
agendaSections.append(
    $('<li>', {
        class: "dd-item",
        'data-id': data.SectionId,
        id: data.SectionId,
    }).append(
        $('<div>', { class: 'dd-handle', text: data.SectionText })
    )
);
```

This also prevents HTML injection if `SectionText` is user-provided data.

Answer (score 1):

The method `appendChild` is from native js. `agendaSections` is a jQuery element, so you need to use `append()` method from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `generateRemoveSectionDropDown` method code to this:

```
function generateRemoveSectionDropDown() {
    $("#nestable ol#agenda-root>li").each( function() {
       $('#RemoveSectionId').append($('<option>', {text: $(this).text() }));
    });
}
```

And add to your html this:

```
<select id="RemoveSectionId"></select>
```

It will work well.

See [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/5xPEsz?p=preview).